# Pandas read_sql() - AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I am trying to read data from MySQL query using pandas read_sql() method with python3+sqlalchemy+pymysql

I tried to follow the following tutorials -

https://pythondata.com/quick-tip-sqlalchemy-for-mysql-and-pandas/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-4EpNdlSuY

https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/101381/pandas.read_sql

Everything just looks good with the code

```py
import pandas
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:mypass@example.com:3306/mydatabase')
df = pandas.read_sql("SELECT * FROM persons", con = engine)
```

Receiving following error -

> AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'

When I tried to pass the 'connection' variable instead of the 'engine', like below -

```py
import pandas
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:mypass@example.com:3306/mydatabase')
connection = engine.connect()
df = pandas.read_sql("SELECT * FROM persons", con = connection)
```

it says -

> AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'cursor'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Strange. Could you try using `pandas.read_sql_query()` instead? What versions of pandas and sqlalchemy are installed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reference - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23030#issuecomment-428140488

The problem went away when I

- Saved my workbook
- Restarted the PC
- Reloaded

It seems like something was cached. I could use read_sql() and other pandas sql functions by passing 'engine' reference -

```py
import pandas
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:mypass@example.com:3306/mydatabase')
df = pandas.read_sql("SELECT * FROM persons", con = engine)
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer I tried shutting down my jupyter notebook and restart it, which actually worked. Restarting my computer was not necessary. Thanks

Comment: Worked like a charm for me! Jupyter should definitely fix this, I ended up wasting 2-3 hours trying to debug this issue.

Comment: Hours and hours debugging and this ended up being the correct answer. Most grateful.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [`pyodbc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835770/move-data-from-pyodbc-to-pandas) and `sqlalchemy` is another way of query db , check with https://towardsdatascience.com/sqlalchemy-python-tutorial-79a577141a91

```
import sqlalchemy as sq
engine = sq.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:mypass@example.com:3306/mydatabase')
connection = engine.connect()
metadata = sq.MetaData()
persons = sq.Table('persons', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

Ret = connection.execute(sq.select([persons]))
youdf=pd.DataFrame(Ret.fetchall())
```

Comment: I got `AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'execution_options'` errors after upgrading pandas and sqlalchemy from an old notebook using OP’s syntax, and querying your way worked.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to a version mismatched.  I had a similar error with an old notebook which used to work fine :

> AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'execution_options'

After a few tests I figured the issue appeared with pandas 1.1.0.  In the [release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html) the minimum version for SQLAlchemy was 1.1.4.  Upgrading SQLAlchemy to this version fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am using MySQL on Win10 with Python 3.10 and Alchemy 1.4

I tried a variety of options nada.  THey all blew up, so here is a work around that seems to make everyone happy.

`    metadata_obj = MetaData()
tbl_test= Table("test", metadata_obj, autoload_with=engine)

```
with engine.connect() as sql_con:
    qry = select(tbl_test)
    resultset = sql_con.execute(qry)
    results_as_dict = resultset.mappings().all()
    df = pd.DataFrame(results_as_dict)
    pprint(df)
```

`