# How to iterate a pyodbc result set multiple times?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am querying a SQL Server table from Python like following:

```
query = "SELECT PN, PD, VT FROM inpat"
data = cursor.execute(query)
```

Next, I am iterating `data` like following

```
for i in data:
    print(i)
```

Above loop works. However, I want to iterate `data` multiple time like following

```
for j in data:
    print(j)
```

The second `for loop` is not printing anything. How I can iterate `data` for multiple times?

Comment: You exhaust the cursor after looping through `data`. If you want to use the data multiple times, store it into a list like `l = list(data)` and then you can iterate through it repeatedly (without having to re-query the db).

Answer (score 0):

It's a cursor, not an in-memory collection.  As you iterate it results are pulled from the server and consumed.  To re-iterate, you must re-run the query with

```
data = cursor.execute(query)
```

But instead of running the query multiple times you should probably just load the data into a Pandas DataFrame, eg [Read data from pyodbc to pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835770/read-data-from-pyodbc-to-pandas)

Comment: "data = cursor.execute(query)" takes long time due to the table size. Is it possible to run "data = cursor.execute(query)" just once?

Comment: Sure.  Just load the data into a Pandas data frame or somesuch.

Answer (score 0):

You can also iterate through the result set multiple times if you use `.fetchall()` to pull it into a list of pyodbc.Row objects:

```py
data = crsr.execute(
    """\
SELECT 'foo' AS thing
UNION ALL
SELECT 'bar' AS thing
"""
).fetchall()

for row in data:
    print(row.thing)
"""
foo
bar
"""

for row in data:
    print(row.thing)
"""
foo
bar
"""
```